# sbt run a resource generator conditionally

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project in which I need to generate my ui from sources to resources using a third party cli. To achieve that i did the following:

```
Compile / resourceGenerators += {
  // do my stuff here
}.taskValue
```

This works just fine, but since it is a long running task, I only want it to be executed, when I specifically say so (e.g. by a command with arguments). Thus, I'm trying to create such a command that calls run with different Compile settings. I read a lot about sbt/settings/tasks/commands etc. but im kind of lost.

Edit:
As Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez has commented, there is a way to cache files and only run a task when said files have changed. Unfortunatelly this does not solve my problem, since i might have changes to the respective files, but still do not want to build them. This is due to the fact, that I have a development server running, that live reloads my ui whenever I change it. Thus, while developing, I do not need to execute the costly build-task for my ui, but rather only want recompile my scala classes and restart the application.

Comment: You can cache the resource generators as mentioned in the official docs: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html - Here is an example of how that looks like: https://github.com/sonar-scala/sonar-scala/pull/172/files

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In fact, I am already using this, but unfortunately this does not solve my problem. Maybe I need to be more precise in my question. I will update the question.

Comment: I mean, you can totally move that logic out of the source generator itself and just be a custom task but that is a bad idea since now anyone contributing to your code would need to know about such a task and when to run it. Rather, if you follow a good caching policy it should just happen when it needs to.

Comment: Unfortunately even the best caching policy (I can think of) will not meet our needs, since building the ui is in most cases not necessary during ui development. So for our small team the benefit of faster restarting will outweigh the risk. Thanks anyway for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my (I admit it, very specific) problem using Def.TaskDyn and a settingKey. In case someone with a similar problem comes here:

```
 lazy val buildUi = Def.settingKey[Boolean]("to build or not to build")

 Compile / resourceGenerators += Def.taskDyn {
      if (buildUi.value) {
        // build here and return the files
      } else {
        Def.task[Seq[File]]{Seq.empty}
      }
    }
```

For ease of use I also added to command aliases:

```
addCommandAlias("buildUiOff", "set buildUi := false")
addCommandAlias("buildUiOn", "set buildUi := true")
```

Edit:
the project definition:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "ProjectName",
    // default behaviour: building on
    buildUi := true,
...
```

and for running without building in sbt shell

```
>buildUiOff
>run
```